# Sorting with a comparator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

In python 3.x the use of comparators is deprecated. Instead python relies on a `key` function the assigns a key values to each element and uses those keys to sort. But this is a problem when there is a complicated way to determine whether one element should come before another.

Example: A set of string should be sorted alphabetically, except that if the first letter of a string is `x` it should come first.

E.g.: `a, b, xaaa, c, xbbb, bxa, bax` should be sorted to `xaaa, xbbb, a, b, bax, bxa, c`.

hos can this sorting be implemented in python?

Comment: In your output, `x < a`, so the possible result should be: `x, xaaa, xbbb, a, b, bxa, bax`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA No, because `x` is not the first letter of `bxa, bax`

Comment: Huh? How did `x` even get into the output, and where did `c` go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, using `str.startswith`:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'xaaa', 'c', 'xbbb', 'bxa', 'bax']
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda k: (not k.startswith('x'), k)))
```

Prints:

```
['xaaa', 'xbbb', 'a', 'b', 'bax', 'bxa', 'c']
```